# Lazy load images from URL in UIScrollView and UITableViewController

Tags: iphone

I want lazy load images from url in UIScrollView in my project ,I searched for stack over flow , but was not able to search suitable example , so please help don't mark as a duplicate , how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the NINetworkImageView class from Verkoey's open source [Nimbus](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus) framework. Simple, easy to code, caches images so you can fetch them again without network IO.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) open source library.

It provides:

- An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to theCocoa Touch framework
- An asynchronous image downloader
- An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling

It is very powerful, yet quick and easy to setup.